# YII how change database structure

Tags: yii

There is a working site on the YII framework.
It should be added to form one new field. I added a column in a database table, in the model class add the field and to the rules of the method, added field in view. But the data are entered in this field are not stored in the database. How to fix it? Other fields are stored properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It a  good practice to prevent this type of `error`. whenever you add any `field` in `table` after `Model` creation just add that `attribute` in `safe` rule in `rules()` `function`.

Inside your `Model.php`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // all other rules

            array('newattribute', 'safe'),
        );
    }
```